# Login and register android error while import android project

Tags: android

I m importing the project and testing the login and register android app but it show the error when run it after this photo it's stop`http://10.0.2.2/learn2crack_login_api/ is it correct ?`
[image: it show]
and in the log cat[image: logcat]

Answer (score 0):

The app has crashed due to a null pointer exception in onPostExecute method written in your Register.java file on line number 237 as per the logcat. You may debug and check the null object or avoid the crash by performing a null check on the object before using it.